# GPS Mapping Exclude Area : SQL, Math, Cold Fusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion, gps, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I'm looking to take a square area in the middle of a larger area and exclude/remove those results.

This code grabs my outside area and works fine.

```
  <cfquery name="q" datasource="ds">
    select * from master
    where ( gpslat > #area.bgpslat# and gpslat < #area.tgpslat# ) and ( gpslong > #area.lgpslong# and gpslong < #area.rgpslong# )  
    and eventdate like '%2016%'
  </cfquery>
```

On same concept, I have created an exclusion area : exbgpslat, extgpslat, exlgpslong, exrgpslong

And I want to remove the ex ones from results... I am using this code...

```
 <cfquery name="q" datasource="ds">
   select * from master
   where ( gpslat > #area.bgpslat# and gpslat < #area.tgpslat# ) and ( gpslong > #area.lgpslong# and gpslong < #area.rgpslong# )
   and ( gpslat > #area.exbgpslat# and gpslat < #area.extgpslat# ) and ( gpslong > #area.exlgpslong# and gpslong < #area.exrgpslong# )   
  and eventdate like '%2016%'
  </cfquery>
```

I get results from the inside box with this... And excludes the outside box.

Am I doing bad math and SQL statements.

This EXCEPT statement doesn't work.

```
 <cfquery name="test" datasource="fire_report">
  select * from master
  where ( gpslat > #area.bgpslat# and gpslat < #area.tgpslat# ) and ( gpslong > #area.lgpslong# and gpslong < #area.rgpslong# ) 
  and statignore = 0 and eventdate like '%2016%'
    EXCEPT
  select * from master
  where ( gpslat > #area.exbgpslat# and gpslat < #area.extgpslat# ) and ( gpslong > #area.exlgpslong# and gpslong < #area.exrgpslong# )
  and statignore = 0 and eventdate like '%2016%'
 </cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know geohash [wikilink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).
It is good for handle your problem.

Comment: I'm using Google Maps API, this isn't a Geo problem.  Its how to write the SQL call to get the outside area and exclude the inside area.